# How to change the start page for IE outside of IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, url

I downloaded some software that apparently changed my "home URL" (terminology?) from google to some other haywire search site. When I went into Tools | whatever in IE (I can't run IE right now) to change it back, I accidentally entered "http:/www.google.com" (missed one of the slashes). So now IE won't run at all - any attempt to use it causes never-ending err msgs to say "Cannot find 'http:/www.google.com'

Is there a way to fix this outside of IE? I guess I should switch to Firefox, but all of my bookmarks are there in IE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to start IE with a command line like the following one

explorer.exe http://www.google.com

it will open a new explorer with this address and not the start page

Otherwise, I think the start page information is saved in the registry (just search for "http:/www.google.com" and you will probably hit one or more keys with explicit names